# How to validate fields

Tags: codeigniter

I want to insert validate data into database.
My code is like below, where submit is my button name and name, email, mobile is my form fields:

```
if($this->input->post('submit'))
{
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $mobile = $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'Mobile','trim|required|numeric');
    $query = $this->my_model->insertdata($name, $email, $mobile);
}
```

How can I validate form fields if I have written code like above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Form Validation Library](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html).

First, autoload it:

Open `application/config/autoload.php` and edit line 61 like below:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('form_validation');
```

Now, you can validate your form in your controller. Here is an example for you:

```
public function some_function()
{
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('input_name', 'input human name', 'required');

 if ($this->form_validation->run() === false)
 {
   //return some error here
 }
 else 
 {
  // send data to your model (e.g. $this->Some_model->some_function())
 }
}
```

Please see [Form Validation Library Guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html) to see all references and examples. Also please follow this order for submitting forms: View -> Controller -> Model.

Comment: can i apply validation in my own code, I tried it in mobile form field, is it wrong?

Comment: @TejasweeChopde sorry, I couldn't understand what you mean? Can you be more spesific? Thanks.

Comment: I tried to put validation on my code which is in question , but it's not possible, so according to your answer i changed my code and it's helpful for me.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

first, you are putting insecure data into your database.

```
$data = [
  'name' => html_escape($this->input->post('name'),
  'email' => html_escape($this->input->post('email'),
  'mobile' => html_escape($this->input->post('mobile');
];

   $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile',Mobile','trim|required|numeric');

   $this->form_validation->set_rules('name',name','trim|required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('email',Email','trim|required|valid_email');
   if ($this->form_validation->run() === false)
   {
       //print error
   }else
   {
      $this->db->insert('TABLE', $data);
   }
```

Comment: sorry sir, but code give me so many error, i have tried by another way which i post my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
public function register()
{
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Usename Name', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[30]');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email ID', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[jobseeker_registration.email]');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'Mobile', 'trim|required|numeric');


if ($this->form_validation->run() === false)
   { $this->load->view('register'); }
else 
 {
  $data = array(
                'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'mobile' => $this->input->post('mobile'),
                'password' => $this->input->post('password')
            );

$this->Jobseeker_model->insertdata($data)
 }
}
```

This code is work for me very well for form validation

Comment: You are still putting insecure data into your database and leaves you wide open to getting hacked

Comment: so ,what I do sir?

Comment: Validation is not the same as escaping the inputs. Validaton only says you are getting the type of information you expect. You should use html_escape on all incoming data inputs. Look in the codeigniter information for html_escape